# Extracting dates from MYSQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table of events:

Fields are: Name, start-date and end-date.

Within my web page I now want to draw a calendar for a whole month

To create the page, I am iterating though the days of the month, and want to check if there is an event already booked on these days. Eg. If the date appears between the start and end date of any records in the table.

I'm pretty sure I don't want to run 31 queries so after the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Load the events in an array and check the array instead of the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 31 queries, you can fetch the entire month and do the rest in your PHP code.

```
SELECT
    `name`,
    `start-date`,
    `end-date`
FROM
    `table of events`
WHERE
    `start-date` BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59:59'
OR
    `end-date` BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59:59';
```

It will provide you information about all events that start or end in the given period. Do with it whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT name, start-date, end-date from Events WHERE (start-day >= $firstDayOfMonth AND start-day <= $lastDayOfMonth) OR (end-day >= $firstDayOfMonth AND end-day <= $lastDayOfMonth)";
```

This will give you all events that start or end in the given month.

$firstDayOfMonth, $lastDayOfMonth - you should calculate these in your php code depending on users input.